# Comparing Two Textfield in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plsql, apex

I have two text fields in my form.
The following are the values of my two text fields

> TEXTFIELD1 =
>   7369:7499:7521:7566:7654:7698:7782:7788:7839:7844:7876:7900:7902:7934
>
> TEXTFIELD2 = 7566

How to check if the value of TEXTFIELD2 does exist in TEXTFIELD1?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use string function `includes`

Assuming the ID of textfields are `textfield1` and `textfield2`, :

```
var txt1 = $('#textfield1');
var txt2 = $('#textfield2');

if(txt1.val().includes(txt2.val())) {
    //action
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use Javascript [IndexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp). It will return the index of the string found inside the first string. It will return -1 if it is not found. So, you that as the condition to check for the desired string.

```js
let TEXTFIELD1 = "7369:7499:7521:7566:7654:7698:7782:7788:7839:7844:7876:7900:7902:7934"
let TEXTFIELD2 = "7566"

if (TEXTFIELD1.indexOf(TEXTFIELD2) > -1){
  console.log("Text Found!");
}
else {
  console.log("Text Not Found!");
}
```